# SVG file from QGIS crashes Illustrator

Tags: svg, qgis-2.18, illustrator

I just upgraded to QGIS 2.18 Las Palmas. I exported an SVG file from Print Composer, as usual, but the SVG file crashes Adobe Illustrator. In fact, it locks up my entire system.

The SVG file is only 11.5 MB. This has never happened to me before, and it has brought my professional workflow to a standstill.

UPDATE:

I tried it in the old 2.8 Wien version and got the same problem. It appears the offending layer was a shapefile for water polygons. Too many nodes I guess. The SVG file imports fine without that layer.

I even tried exporting the water polygon layer by itself, but Illustrator still could not open it. That's pretty sad. I'm just surprised that this is the first time it's happened to me.